# animate scrolling matching the name not working fine

Tags: jquery

```
$("a.scroll").click(function(){

    if(this.hash){
        //get rid of hash
        var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

        //get the position of <a name>
        var $toElement = $("a[name="+hash+"]");
        var toPosition = $toElement.offset().top - 250;

        //scroll/animate that element
        $("body,html").animate({

            scrollTop : toPosition

        },1000,"easeOutExpo");

        return false;
    }
});

if(location.hash){
    var hash = location.hash;
    window.scroll(0,0);
    $("a[href="+hash+"]").click();
}
```

when i am trying to match the name string and scrolling it to the location its hiding it behind the header, my header is fixed.. on scrolling..

and also facing the problem when resize the window, header takes extra space and scrolling hides the content behind.. how to fix it//

Comment: `this.hash` - hash of an element? That's not gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` element doesn't have a `hash` member. Check the console for any errors before posting. You need to get the `href` attribute's content. You might be needing something like this:

```
$("a.scroll").click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  if (href.indexOf("#") === 0) {
    //get rid of hash
    var hash = href.substr(1);
    //get the position of <a name>
    var $toElement = $("a[name=" + hash + "]");
    var toPosition = $toElement.offset().top - 250;
    //scroll/animate that element
    $("body,html").animate({
      scrollTop: toPosition
    }, 1000, "easeOutExpo");
    return false;
  }
});
```